# Ubuntu zeroc-ice install error

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to install ZeroC Ice but am getting the following errors.

```
vagrant@marvin:~$ sudo apt-get install zeroc-ice34
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
zeroc-ice34 : Depends: php-zeroc-ice (>= 3.4.2-4ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas or help on how to resolve this?

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-zeroc-ice?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus that just throws more dependency errors

Comment: sudo apt-get build-deps php-zeros-ice, otherwise you just have to install the dependencies.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus thanks but the error was using ubuntu 12.04 instead of >12.10